# Android app hangs while trying to open two DataInputStreams

Tags: java, android, url, inputstream, datainputstream

I'm writing this app where I need to open two InputStreams simultaneously with a capability of switching to either streams in order to stream images. I could open the first stream but when I try to open the second stream it hangs. Following is the code and I have made a comment where it hangs and could you explain whether i am doing something wrong?

```
public boolean Start()
    {
        numberOfServicesUsingThisInstanceLock.lock();

        if (numberOfServicesUsingThisInstance > 0)
        {
            numberOfServicesUsingThisInstance++;
            return true; 
        }

        // else 
        numberOfServicesUsingThisInstance = 1;

        bisList.clear();
        disList.clear();        
        FrameTimeStampList.clear();

        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.objConfig.lstCameraInfo.size(); i++)
            {
                FrameTimeStampList.add(Long.valueOf("-1"));
                final CameraInfo ci = this.objConfig.lstCameraInfo.get(i);
                String sourceUrl = GetMjpegUrlForCam(this.Type, ci.brand, ci.ipAddress);

                Log.d("DUMPMJPEG_START", "URL: " + sourceUrl);

                if (sourceUrl == "NONE") continue;

                URL url = new URL(sourceUrl);               

                Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication (ci.userName, ci.password.toCharArray());
                    }
                });

                Log.d("DUMPMJPEG_START", "OpenStream");
                InputStream in = url.openStream(); // CODE HANGS HERE
                Log.d("DUMPMJPEG_START", "Creating DataInputStream");
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(in);
                Log.d("DUMPMJPEG_START", "DataInputStream added to the DataInputStream List");

                Log.d("DUMPMJPEG_START", "adding BufferedInputStreams to the list");
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(dis);
                Log.d("DUMPMJPEG_START", "BufferendInputStreams added to the list");
                disList.add(dis);
                bisList.add(bis);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.getMessage();
        }
        return false;       
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say it hangs, don't you get any response for a long time or do you get an exception?

More to your code:

1. You open streams but never close them. Or will you have that control on another part of your app?
2. It is a bad idea to open streams and not use some sort of connection timeout.
3. The exception won't print anything as you should print it with e.printStackTrace() or send the message to some log/output.

Comment: I don't get any response at all for a long time and No II don't get any exceptions  1)I have a different part of the app which controls them 2)Agreed 3) Agreed, but there is no exception caused here when i debugged it..

Comment: Well, it seems as if you are having connectivity issues with the server. When you connect from outside the code, does it work? Are you testing from the Android emulator? How about a unit test for this functionality?

Comment: yeah I guess so but im sure its not connectivity issues because I could open the first stream but not the second one!. no im using a device

Comment: And what if you switch the order of the IPs so the first becomes the second and the second the first, it should fail somehow, it really seems as if it cannot connect. Another thought, Android has many restrictions, have you checked if there's some Android Permission you did not set? At least you should have the INTERNET permission in your Manifest...